Bootable USB for Ubuntu 22.04 not detected on Dell Precision 3540
I just bought a Dell Precision 3540 laptop on Amazon. I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on it. (FYI, I tested my bootable USB stick on my Lenovo IdeaPad 3 and it worked fine so that's not the problem) When I start the computer with the stick plugged in and go into the one-time boot menu using the F12 key, the USB stick does not show up on the list of boot options. I get only Windows Boot Manager , onboard NIC(IPV4) and onboard NIC(IPV6). I tried disabling secure boot and switching from full RAID to AHCI but this did not work. Ubuntu 22.04 should be UEFI compliant and also support RAID so I am really struggling to figure out what the problem here is.
I haven't tried testing a Windows bootable USB yet, so I don't know if the issue is Linux-specific, but I don't expect that it would be.
If I absolutely need to, I will return the machine and go with trusty Lenovo again, but I'd rather not as the build quality and keyboard on the Dell are a bit nicer than the Lenovo, in my experience.

Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Usually Windows or even Dell updates firmware.  Some just find different flash drive, different installer, or different port then works? Dell Inspiron 3567 Review i3 7100u (Works well)
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364642
Dell Precision 3520 Turn off RAID & change to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096492/installing-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows10-the-ssd-is-not-recognized  My Dell 5310 just worked with Intel VMD driver, so AHCI not required for it. But Windows fast startup & bitlocker had to be off.

Check your Bios/Eufi settings andthe following:
Check Secure Boot
Ensure Secure Boot is disabled
UEFI and Legacy Settings
Confirm that both UEFI and Legacy modes are enabled if the BIOS allows this.
USB boot options and boor order:
Verify that USB boot options are enabled and prioritized in the boot order settings
Confirm that the boot order is set with USB HDD.
Some Laptops need USB FDD, and USB CD as options too.
I don’t think this is the issue, but check in the BIOS to ensure that USB ports are enabled on booting, if you got this option.

Thanks for the answer Z0OM. A combination of factory resetting the BIOS, disabling secure boot, and changing from RAID to AHCI worked for me. Must have forgot to do one of those things the first time round. Thanks again.
